# Page not showing in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to build a simple React web app using routes and contexts, but whereas the context is working just fine, the HomePage isn't rendering properly.

Any ideas?

Here's my `App.js` code:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { HomePage } from './pages';
import { ROUTES } from './routes';
import { UserProvider } from './contexts'; 
import { Navigation } from './components';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <UserProvider>
        <Navigation>
          <Router>
            <main>
              <Routes>
                <Route path={ROUTES.Home} element={<HomePage />} />
              </Routes>
            </main>
          </Router>
        </Navigation>
      </UserProvider>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Some debugging info:
-> the value of {ROUTES.Home} is "/"
-> Navigation is a simple header with some user info entered at login, and using the UserProvider context. This is rendering just fine...

On my HomePage I would have to see this rendered in the DOM, but all is blank even after stripping the List component to a simple `<div>test</div>`:

```
import { List } from '../components';

const HomePage = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>HOME</h1>
      <div>test</div>
    </>
  )
};
export default HomePage;
```

---

Also, not sure if related, in my Inspector Elements (using Chrome) I see this:

```
<!--
  This HTML file is a template.
  If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

  You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
  The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

  To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
  To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
-->
```

---

Big thanks in advance :)

Comment: We're missing debugging details here. What's `<Navigation>`? What's the value of `ROUTES.Home`? Does it correspond to the path in your navigator? Is `<App>` displayed?

Comment: Thnx for your reaction @Arkellys, much appreciated... Apologies for the incomplete info. Added additional info in the question.

Comment: Make sure you open your dev console and configure your editor correctly, you should have noticed errors regarding the wrong imports.

Answer (score 1):

HomePage is default export so you've to use like this

```
import  HomePage  from './pages';
```

Comment: Thnx Hithesh, you are absolutely right, but it didn't solve my problem unfortunately :-/

Comment: can you share the any codesand box link

Comment: this ok Hithesh? https://github.com/Jpetillion/petitlist.git - I'm not so familiar with codesandbox ; hope github will do... again greatly appreciated!

Comment: @BBJinx Your import for `Navigation` is wrong too

Comment: true @Arkellys, thnx for pointing that out. Unfortunately it's not solving my issue. Hadn't seen any errors on it either ...

Comment: @BBJinx `Navigation` doesn't return its children.

Comment: That was the issue! You solved it @Arkellys - thank you so much for helping me out! Great to be part of such a caring and supportive community... Thnx (again :) ... !